# Typo3 automatic create gallery

Tags: gallery, lightbox, typo3

I'd like to have a gallery just with one set of pictures in one size. This pictures would rendered in a specific size on the page and if I click on an image, a lightbox gallery with the picture in original size opens. 
The part with the smaller pictures is already done with this TypoScript code:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.file.maxH = 177
tt_content.image.20.1.file.maxW = 267
```

now I'd like to automatic wrap all images on a page in an a-tag, reference on themself and add a class and rel attribute. 
Is that possible?
I read something about imageLinkWrap and tried a [tutorial](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Imagelinkwrap/Index.html#imagelinkwrap-example-fancybox) but it doesn't work. It was this code:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap {
JSwindow = 0
  directImageLink = 1
  linkParams.ATagParams {
    dataWrap = class = "lightbox" rel="lightbox{field:uid}"
  }
}
```

Shouldn't it wrap the image with an a-tag with class and rel params?

**EDIT: one Problem solved.**

I forgot to overwrite the imageLinkWrap with

`tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap >`

and to enable it with

```
tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap.enable=1
```

Comment: enable = 1 does not exist. Check with Template> TypoScript Object Browser whether you did it right. We also need your TYPO3 CMS version.

Comment: Thats funny, because with the enable = 1 line, it works and without, it doesn't.
I have TYPO3 6.0.4

Comment: what is missing? What do you get, what do you expect?

Comment: without enable = 1 the a tag around the image is missing. with enable = 1 it is as it should be